# FRDM-KL25Z programming using InterruptIn

Tags: microcontroller, programming

I am trying to develop a software to FRDM-KL25Z that needs a button. Anytime this button is pressed, I need the variable "select" to increase by 1, so I designed the function changeSelection:

```
void changeSelection() {
   selection = selection + 1;

   if (selection > 3)
     selection = 0;
}
```

But, when I use this on the main function, I get the error: "Expression must have class type "button.rise(&changeSelection)" ". What am I missing?

```
InterruptIn button(PTA2);
void main() {
   button.rise(&changeSelection);

   while {
     ...do some stuff...
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are u trying to detect if a button is pressed or not from interrupt?

Comment: Yes, is it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is based on your comment in the question. 
Since your main aim is to detect if a switch is pressed or not, a sample algorithm would look like:

```
ISR:

wait for pin to go low(depends on switch)
 if low,increment a variable
 else,clear the variable

If variable is greater than debounce time for switch(70ms maybe for switches)
 Set,Switch pressed flag


Main:

while(1)
{
 if Switch is pressed
  do something(may be increment "selection" here)
}
```

If your interrupt is configured to trigger every 1ms,the Switch pressed flag will set when atleast 70 consecutive low values are read at the pin.
Detecting if a pin is pressed or not using an interrupt everytime the value at the pin changes may not be a good idea due to noise.Use a timer interrupt instead.

For details regarding the syntax of your code,I suggest [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).